# Apache errors - invalid argument & Bogus version

Tags: apache

I keep seeing the same two errors for referees to my site. Quite a high traffic site so we get them often enough. I'm just trying to deduce why they appear. At first I just assumed that these where probably people turning away before the page loads etc. But now I'm worried it could be a bug in Apache or something worse at my end.

The two errors are:

```
(22)Invalid argument: AH01075: Error dispatching request to : *Page Location*

AH01068: Got bogus version 98, referer: *Page Location*
```

The 98 in bogus version changes sometimes to other numbers.

Has anyone got any experience with these errors and how to resolve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `date.timezone` in your `php.ini` is not empty! Took ages to figure that out!
Valid values are listed here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Thanks ill give that a look

Comment: Had the same problem when this happens on a submit page than he send the data two times. So i hope this will fix the problem!

Comment: I have the same problem, but this solution doesn't work for me :(